# #ifndef in Common Lisp

Tags: include, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

In C, to make sure we don't re-include headers that are included we use the following structure:

```
#ifndef UTILS
#define UTILS

#include "my_utils.h"

#endif
```

I've broken my Lisp program into separate files; multiple files sometimes use the same file (e.g., my_utilities is used by multiple files). When I run the program, I get warnings that I am redefining things (calling `load` of the same file multiple times).

This would be fixed by doing something similar to `#ifndef` in C. What is the Common Lisp equivalent or standard method of doing this?

I am fairly new to Lisp. Let me know if there are best practices (perhaps,  a different method of structuring my programs?) that I am missing.

Comment: You should use [asdf](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/common-lisp/670/asdf-another-system-definition-facility#t=20160727160132848467) to define a system.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The question you asked

The direct analogue of preprocessor conditions like `#if` in C is the
[`#+`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhq.htm) read-time conditionalization facility.

## The question you wanted to ask

To avoid multiple loading of a file, you can either use the standard
(but deprecated)
[`provide`/`require`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_provid.htm) facility,
or an add-on system like [ASDF](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/).

Comment: That is what I wanted to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

1. For Common Lisp applications and libraries it is preferred to use a *system* management tool. Like ASDF or whatever your implementation may provide. A system is a collection of files with dependencies and various actions (load, compile, ...).
2. You can always check the state of the runtime and do something.

Example:

```
(unless (fboundp 'foobar)
  (require "foo")
  (load "bar"))

(unless (find-package 'foobar)
  (require "foo")
  (load "bar"))
```

3. `PROVIDE` and `REQUIRE` are built-in functions for exactly that. If you require a *module* it will be loaded, unless already `provided`. Unfortunately this functionality is underspecified in the standard, but implementations may provide useful functionality.
4. Common Lisp runtimes have a list of *features* on the list `*features*`. You can use that to advertise and check functionality.

Example:

In your library:

```
(push :cool-new-graphics-library cl:*features*)
```

In your application code:

```
(when (member :cool-new-graphics-library cl:*features*)
  (funcall (find-symbol "DRAW-SPACE-SHIP" "CNGL")
           :death-star))
```

Common Lisp provides a way to conditionalize that a *read time*. The following code will only be read when the `:cool-new-graphics-library` feature is present, and thus it only then will be executed later:

```
#+cool-new-graphics-library(cngl:draw-space-ship :death-star)
```

Common Lisp also allows you to express some logic:

```
#+(and lispworks cool-new-graphics-library)
  (cngl:draw-space-ship :enterprise)

#-cool-new-graphics-library(warn "no cool graphics library available")
```

Note that you can force Lisp to execute code at compile-time:

```
(eval-when (:load-toplevel :compile-toplevel :execute)
  #+(and lispworks cool-new-graphics-library)
    (cngl:draw-space-ship :enterprise)

  #-cool-new-graphics-library(warn "no cool graphics library available")
 )
```

For this to work the `EVAL-WHEN` has to be at the toplevel in a file. That means it will not work deep in nested forms. It does work inside a toplevel `PROGN`,`LOCALLY`, `MACROLET` and `SYMBOL-MACROLET`, though.

Thus `EVAL-WHEN` allows you to run code which is part of the file which is currently compiled. This code than can look for loaded systems, provided modules, available functions, and more.

Comment: Very thorough. Thank you.